# Filter by many2many (or foreignkey) that has a LOT of values, in django admin (grappelli or not)

Tags: django, django-admin, django-1.4, django-grappelli, django-admin-filters

I have two models:

```
class TheMainThing(models.Model):
    ... some fields ...
    type = ManyToManyField('Type')

class Type(models.Model):
    ...more fields...
```

I would like to enable filtering `TheMainThings` in the admin by `Types`. The only Issue is that there are like 100k or more of the `Type` objects, so it isn't practical doing it with standard built-in filters. That's because all the `Types` get loaded in browser as an available option. (Actually, I'm using Grappelli, but I believe it's the same with standard Django admin).

It there a *don't_reinvent_the_wheel* approach to this problem?

I like Grappelli's autocomplete widget on raw_id fields, I imagine something like that would be ideal for this problem... It there such a thing?

**edit:**
To clarify - the main problem is load time and memory consumption in browser, not the presentation.

Comment: I'd start looking at various django foreign key filtering solutions out there; ultimately the view receives a list of PKs so those solutions should work with M2M without much trouble. 

I have yet to find a great plug and play library without tweaking. I'm interested in how you solved your problem! Starring.

Comment: @YujiTomita you said "various django foreign key filtering solutions out there"... Any particular one that you have in mind? :)

Answer (score 0):

The admin outputs those filters as links with query strings inside `<ul>`s. You could change those out for selects instead.

The template used there is `admin/filter.html` and it looks like this:

```
{% load i18n %}
<h3>{% blocktrans with filter_title=title %} By {{ filter_title }} {% endblocktrans %}</h3>
<ul>
{% for choice in choices %}
    <li{% if choice.selected %} class="selected"{% endif %}>
    <a href="{{ choice.query_string|iriencode }}">{{ choice.display }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

You can provide your own by the same name to override theirs, so redo it maybe like this:

```
{% load i18n %}
<h3>{% blocktrans with filter_title=title %} By {{ filter_title }} {% endblocktrans %}</h3>
<select>
{% for choice in choices %}
    <option data-href="{{ choice.query_string|iriencode }}"
            {% if choice.selected %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>
    {{ choice.display }}
    </option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

Then follow the filter link on change:

```
$(function() {
    $('select', '#changelist-filter').on('change', function(e) {
        window.location = window.location.href + $(e.target).attr('data-href');
    });

});
```

To take it a step further, you could treat those with something like [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/) afterward.

Comment: This is a nice UI tweak, but my main problem is load time, and memory needed at client (browser) for all the available option, regardless of presentation (links or select box). As a metter of fact, Grappelli already does pretty much the same thing as you propose here - every filter is made a dropdown. My problem in two words: too many options.

Comment: Btw, thank you for the info about select2, it seems better that Chosen. (For general usage).

Comment: Ah I see, I missed the point entirely. Another option would be to write a view (or maybe a Tastypie resource) to return filter options as json, and point a select2 widget at that endpoint. Then just render nothing in `admin/filter.html`. Then we're getting back into the realm of reinventing the wheel, though.

Comment: You just keep mentioning good things, thanks! I think I'll go with Tastypie unless some more ready-to-use solution pops up.